# Entry Point Not Found when executing system() in Windows

Tags: c++, c

So, I have two applications, one compiled in C++, other in C.
The main, C app, fails to start the other one using system() function in Windows. I get an error message box saying "Entry Point Not Found". The problem is, the other app works just fine when running from Command Prompt. Has anyone encountered something similar to that?

**EDIT:** - for those who asked :)
Well, the app is in the other directory, it converts a bmp to png, it has two parameters.. Firstly I create a new string like this

```
sprintf(converterExec, "%s\\converter.exe \"%s\" \"%s\"", newDir, bmpLoc, pngLoc);
```

newDir = the program's directory
bmpLoc, pngLoc = locations of two, source and destination files

when I debug the program, `converterExec` contains the absolute path to the program with two parameters, so there is no error there.

then I call this:

```
system(converterExec);
```

Comment: Show us the call to `system`.  Are you passing the full path to the exe - and are you pointing at the *right* exe?

Comment: Did you check that you are running the right app? Did you check that the app runs if the current working Directory is not the apps Directory (do not `cd ...` into the Directory but start it giving an absolute path)?

Comment: I have updated the description for you guys :)

Comment: You probably need quotes around the exe too.

Comment: Pick your language first. Then, provide enough info for others to reproduce it (but not more). Don't insert "edit here" into your question either, just edit it to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, some problem is in your `converter.exe` (perhaps, it should be compiled with static linking).

Try other program, e.g.:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <windows.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
    char commandLine[256];
    char progName[] = "ping";
    char hostName[] = "localhost";
    char keys[] = "-n 2";
    sprintf(commandLine, "%s \"%s\" %s", progName, hostName, keys);
    printf("%s\n", commandLine);
    system(commandLine);
}
```

If it works, try your command again but with adding `cmd /c` in the beginning:

```
 sprintf(converterExec, "cmd /c %s\\converter.exe \"%s\" \"%s\"", newDir, bmpLoc, pngLoc);
```

Also check, that memory allocated for your `converterExec` is enough to store all characters with additional `'\0'` at the end.